# Boostrap ngb-rating half of star

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using ng-rating to display avg value of score. The problem is when average value is like 3.97. Ng-rating still displays it as 3 stars. How can I make it to display like half of a star?
my html:

```
<div style="font-size: x-large; color: orange;"><ngb-rating [max]="5" [(rate)]="overallScore" [readonly]="false"></ngb-rating></div>
```

Example for 3.67 value:
[star](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSQxp.png)

Edit:
While trying solution from bootstrap site 4
[hearts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APdH4.png)
filling of heart is a bit square?

Edit2:

Template:

```
<ng-template #t let-fill="fill">
        <span class="star" [class.full]="fill === 100">
          <span class="half" [style.width.%]="fill">⭐</span>⭐
        </span>
    </ng-template>
```

I have changed code to css

```
 .star {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 3rem;
        color: #d3d3d3;
    }
    .star.full {
        color: #ffa600;
    }
    .star.half {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
        color: #ffa600;
    }
```

and it gives that result:
[stars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHpGv.png)

Comment: Can you include the rest of your code? Also, see this tutorial: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/rating/examples#decimal

Comment: @ShaunLoftin
Do you mean code that calculates avg from given data? Because I don't have any code besides that one. Tried solution from your link but have a slight problem here after copying 1:1 from it.

Answer (score 0):

For the custom template with decimals you can use following:

```
<ng-template #scoreTemplate let-fill="fill">
    <span class="star" [class.full]="fill === 100">
      <span class="half" [style.width.%]="fill">⭐</span>⭐
    </span>
</ng-template>

<ngb-rating max="5"
  [(rate)]="overallScore"
  [readonly]="true"
  [starTemplate]="scoreTemplate">
</ngb-rating>
```

but you also need the styles:

```
.star {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #d3d3d3;

  &.full {
    color: #ffa600;
  }

  &.half {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #ffa600;
  }
}
```

For just half a star and not all decimals you can use:

```
<ng-template #scoreTemplate let-fill="fill">
    <span class="star" [class.full]="fill < 50">
      <span class="half" [style.width.%]="fill >= 50 ? 50 : 0">⭐</span>⭐
    </span>
</ng-template>
```

Also, you can replace the emoji with your custom icon.

Comment: I tried to use your code but changing from scss to css (because that I assume it is) and I get result that you can see in main post in edit2. Did I made mistake while trying to convert from scss to css or it is something else?

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<ngb-rating [max]="5"[(rate)]="overallScore" [readonly]="false">
    <ng-template let-fill="fill">
       <span class="star" [class.full]="fill===100"><span class="half"[tyle.width.%]="fill">&#9733;</span>&#9733;</span>
    </ng-template>
</ngb-rating>
```

**style page**

```
.star {
   height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding-top:5px;
  color: #d3d3d3;

  }

 .full {
   color: #ffa600;
  }
.starClass{
   position: absolute;
   display: inline-block;
   bottom: 30%;
   padding-top:4px;
   height:35px;
   color: #ffa600;
   overflow: hidden;

}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing and why you believe it is the best approach?